# Django CSRF verification failed

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have a form in http page say http://example.com and form is like .I m using django 1.3.I enabled csrf middleware and put csrf token tag inside the form.When i try to submit the form i m getting the below error.

> Referer checking failed - http://example.com/ does not match
>   https://example.com/.

Any idea on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: can you post your form template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is difference between `http` and `https`. Are you trying to POST on HTTPS while GET is from HTTP?

If you have HTTPS setup may be you can look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#ssl-https) for validating your configuration.

Comment: Yes get is from http and i m trying to post in https